# SSRS WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() giving me NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have custom code inside of a SSRS report that needs to get the current user. e.g.

```
Dim myPrincipal As New System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal   
   (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
```

I would have expected GetCurrent() to return the principal of the user that was accessing the report; however, it gives me the principal of "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE". Does anyone know how to get ReportServer to run as the user running the report? I checked both web.config, and they both indicate Windows Authentication and Impersonate=True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  I just used

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity
```

instead of

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

This doesn't work when I'm am previewing the report locally i.e.

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name //returns an empty string when previewing locally
```

but it works fine after I deploy to a server.