# SSRS BIDS text box visibility based on AD Logins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I have a text box which I am using as a link to open a webpage.

Is it possible, using the Visibility tab seen below, to cherry pick who is able to see/use this box using AD logins.

Basically there will be 50+ users seeing the screen that I want the link on, but I only want 1 or 2 of them to be able to see that particular link.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268808/how-can-i-determine-what-ad-security-groups-the-current-user-is-in-from-within-a

Comment: Im thinking something along the lines of:
=iif(User!UserID="domain\useridno",TRUE,FALSE)

Comment: yes, read the linked question, or moreso the answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=iif(User!UserID="domain\user_ad",FALSE,TRUE)
```